# Is Javascript not a dynamic programming language, why is the DOM not modified?

Tags: javascript

```js
/* main.js */
myP1 = document.createElement('p');
myP2 = document.createElement('p');

firstDiv = document.querySelector('div');
firstDiv.appendChild(myP1);
firstDiv.appendChild(myP1);

myP1.textContent = 'P1 here';
p2TextContent = myP2.textContent;
p2TextContent = 'P2 here';
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src = 'main.js'></script>
</html>
```

When `myP2.textContent` is assigned to variable `p2TextContent`, `p2TextContent` should be bound to `myP2.textContent`, and if modified `p2TextContent`, `myP2.textContent` should be modified at the same time. But why `myP2.textContent` has not been modified?

Comment: By dynamic they mean user interactive or results driven. You haven't assigned any `.textContent` to `myP2` when your first attempt to get it's value.

Comment: `myP2.textContent` returns plain text, i.e. a primitive, and a line later `p2Content` is just reassigned with a new value. Setting `p2TextContent = myP2.textContent;` doesn't create a magical link between the variable and the HTML element.

Comment: Why would you think it is supposed to work like that? If you want binding, use a template or other system which provides binding.

Comment: everything in js is passed by value, though with objects that value is a pointer to the object...